# Chapel domains : differences between `low/high` and `first/last` methods

Tags: chapel

Chapel domains have two sets of methods

```
domain.low, domain.high
```

and

```
domain.first, domain.last
```

What are the various cases where these return different results (i.e when is `domain.first != domain.low` and `domain.last != domain.high`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that these queries are supported not just on domains, but also on ranges (a simpler type representing an integer sequence upon which many domains, and their domain queries, are based).  For that reason, my answer will initially focus on ranges for simplicity, before returning to dense rectangular domains (which are defined using a range per dimension).

As background, `first` and `last` on a range are designed to specify the indices that you'll get when iterating over that range.  In contrast, `low` and `high` specify the minimal and maximal indices that define the range.

- For a simple range, like `1..10`, `first` and `low` will be the same, evaluating to `1`, while `last` and `high` will both evaluate to `10`
- The way you iterate through a range in reverse order in Chapel is by using a negative stride like `1..10 by -1`.  For this range, `low`  and `high` will still be `1` and `10` respectively, but `first` will be `10` and `last` will be `1` since the range represents the integers 10, 9, 8, ..., 1.
- Chapel also supports non-unit strides, and they can also result in differences.  For example for the range `1..10 by 2`, `low` and `high` will still be `1` and `10` respectively, and `first` will still be `1` but `last` will be `9` since this range only represents the odd values between 1 and 10.

The following program demonstrates these cases along with `1..10 by -2` which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader (you can also [try it online (TIO)](https://tio.run/##dY@xCsIwFEX3fsUlUws1GEfFxcH/iLU2gZCE10gQ8dtjWlBrS8dzz3nDa5T0rUnJk2vgSdtwcnd77Uuq8CyASDq0xpbs7AgkbdeC1aAabM@qwzQAbpr6gOMY8BHmhZE5@BQDLAIX8QtcnHulO/X1A/wFGV5FMf1CcC62eV5suDywEWtmt3qSTUpv)):

```
proc printBounds(r) {
  writeln("For range ", r, ":");
  writeln("  first = ", r.first);
  writeln("  last  = ", r.last);
  writeln("  low   = ", r.low);
  writeln("  high  = ", r.high);
  writeln();
}

printBounds(1..10);
printBounds(1..10 by -1);
printBounds(1..10 by 2);
printBounds(1..10 by -2);
```

Dense rectangular domains are defined using a range per dimension.  Queries like `low`, `high`, `first`, and `last` on such domains return a tuple of values, one per dimension, corresponding to the results of the queries on the respective ranges.  As an example, here's a 4D domain defined in terms of the ranges above ([TIO](https://tio.run/##S85ILEjN@f8/OT@vuETBRcFWodpQT8/QQEcBTCkkVSroGiJxjJAljGqtubjKizJLUnPyNJRy8ssVFIAGKOkouOgBOZrWCLmMzPQMuByIgyyZllkEtBsqCeYgy@YkAiXhxiaCJP//BwA)):

```
const D = {1..10, 1..10 by -1, 1..10 by 2, 1..10 by -2};

writeln("low   = ", D.low);
writeln("high  = ", D.high);
writeln("first = ", D.first);
writeln("last  = ", D.last);
```